# PostGIS - syntax error inserting GeoJSON

Tags: postgis, geojson

I am trying to insert a GeoJSON into PostGIS, but I am encountering a syntax error.  I can't seem to see where the problem is - I'm sure it is an easy issue to resolve, but my inexperienced eyes can't seem to see where the problem is.

Insert statement (PHP):

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgis user=$user password=$password");

$sql = "INSERT INTO carto_doodle (poly_geom) VALUES
    (ST_SetSRID
        (ST_GeomFromGeoJSON
            ({"type":"Feature",
              "properties":{},
              "geometry":{"type":"Polygon",
                          "coordinates":
                              [[[-74.54635620117188,40.773261878622634],
                                [-74.69741821289062,40.61082491956405],
                                [-74.30740356445312,40.61603737424185],
                                [-74.54635620117188,40.773261878622634]]]
                          }
              })
          ),
     4326)"

$success = pg_query($conn, $sql);
```

However, this returns an error for the `$success` line:

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near &quot;{&quot; LINE 1: ...(poly_geom) VALUES (ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON({&quot;type&quot;:&quot;F... ^
```

---

Here's what ended up working for me...

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO carto_doodle (point_geom) VALUES
       (ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(\'
            {"type":"Point",
             "coordinates":
                          [-48.23456, 20.12345]
            }\'
        ), 4326))';
```

Comment: Is that INSERT statement run fine in SQL console ?

Comment: Also note: ST_GeomFromGeoJSON works only for JSON Geometry fragments. It throws an error if you try to use it on a whole JSON document.

Comment: Oh ok cool thanks - I have to put a little more thought into this...

Comment: Yes, thanks @nickves - that was really helpful.  Editing my question to show the final working syntax...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example with  [ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) :

```
  select ST_GeomFromGeoJSON
        ('{"type":"Polygon",
                      "coordinates":
                          [[-74.54635620117188,40.773261878622634],
                            [-74.69741821289062,40.61082491956405],
                            [-74.30740356445312,40.61603737424185],
                            [-74.54635620117188,40.773261878622634]]
          }')
```

Comment: This generates the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'`, referring to the curly brace right after the first single quote you added.

Comment: I have edited with a running example.

Comment: Thanks man, this was really helpful.  After some more experimentation, I was able to get it to work - I've edited my question to show the final syntax...